# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]: MySql Server doesn't start, restart, stop

Tags: mysql

I've got a really hard problem. From one second to the other the `MySql` Server doesn't work anymore. When I try to connect through an application I've got this message "`Connection Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`"...

I don't changed anything...

When I try to restart via `SSH` I get no feedback...

Don't know what to do ;(

Comment: Examine its error log, or run the bare `mysqld` binary without any startup scripts to show what's wrong.

Comment: is this on a dedicated server or local ? and when you do restart does it say stopping mysql and hangs or do you get back to the commandline without any response ?

Comment: @Miguelo hi, thx 4 the quick response. It's a virtual/ dedicated server and yes when I try to restart it hangs ;( also i couldn't find teh mysqld.sock in the directory ??!

Comment: did you restart the whole virtual server ?

Comment: @Miguelo yeah I did also. I've restarted the vs, the apache (just to be sure) and tried the same with the mysql server.

Comment: i think we need some way to chat if you want me to help you, as it can be so many things

Comment: well, that would be fantastic.. can i send you a message with my skype account?

Comment: yes send it to my email

Comment: hmmm, it seems that there is no private messaging function on stackoverflow ?

Comment: your reputation is to low, i have my email at my profile

Comment: ok then check your inbox mail sent

Comment: Insufficient information to answer this question. Please delete.

Answer (score 0):

Check your my.cnf memory settings. It could be that mysql is crashing, and mysqld_safe is restarting it over and over. Maybe there is a brief period you are able to connect before it crashes.

Also useful to post version number etc,

Answer (score 0):

Thx all of us for your replies - specially a big thank-you goes to @Miguelo who helped me a lot via skype.

This was the original error:
130531  8:18:11InnoDB: Warning: difficult to find free blocks from
InnoDB: the buffer pool (72513 search iterations)! Consider
InnoDB: increasing the buffer pool size.

Regards,

GD